# Magento 2: Where is cart data saved?

Tags: magento2, database, session, addtocart

Magento version: 2.0.0

When user add products into cart, where are they saved? $_SESSION or Database? If it is in database, which table?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Magento2,  save cart details at Quote tables.

- For Cart general details use `quote` table .
- Carts item details at `quote_item`.
- Cart items option details at `quote_item_option`

**Additional:**

- Checkout Addressed details at `quote_address`.
- Checkout payment details at `quote_payment`.

Magento2 use  Quote module **Magento_Quote** `(vendor/magento/module-quote)` for save all **Cart general,items detail,address details etc**.

And Mage_Checkout module's Session Cart model make relation between user,session with Cart details

[image]

Comment: How do i get values from quote_address table?

Comment: YOu have to use `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address` or  have to use quote QuoteRepository

Comment: $shippingId = $order->getShippingAddress()->getId();
  $address = $objectManager->create('Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address')->load($shippingId);

var_dump($address)->getData(); = NULL

it didnt give me any data

Comment: @AmitBera, How can I collect abandoned cart details? Please answer to the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59643279/magento2-3-how-to-get-collect-abandoned-cart-data

Comment: @AmitBera I am facing a strange issue where on restore cart data is considered abandoned. Can you help on this?

Answer (score -1):

quote table is not cart. If you delete quote from DB raw by entity_id it will be restored with new entity_id. It will have all items.